# How to change from bash-3.2$ to [user@localhost ~]$ in UNIX

Tags: bash, unix, command-line

I am newbie to UNIX. When I was practicing some commands in UNIX. Earlier the
Prompt was shown like this  "[user@localhost ~]$". After some time it shows "bash-3.2$", but still some commands worked. I tried to change the shell type from bash to ksh and csh. But that didn't worked.
How can I change this bash-3.2$ back to [user@localhost ~]$ in bash shell.

Comment: or http://unix.stackexchange.com/, even http://askubuntu.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

take a look at http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-linux-unix-bash-shell-setup-prompt.html on how to set up the `PS1` variable in bash. It has a wide variety of option

Answer (score 0):

I noticed I got this same issue when I ran

```
Akinjides-MacBook-Pro:Desktop akinjide$ $SHELL

The output was 
bash-3.2$
```

so the `$SHELL` keyword runs the shell specified by the SHELL environment variable.

you can just type `exit` to leave.

if you run

```
Akinjides-MacBook-Pro:Desktop akinjide$ sudo -s

The output was 
bash-3.2#
```

According to `man sudo`

**-s [command]**: The -s (shell) option runs the shell specified by the SHELL environment variable if it is set or the shell as specified in the password database.  If a command is specified, it is passed to the shell for execution via the shell's -c option.  If no command is specified, an interactive shell is executed.

This prompts for your password, and you can just type `exit` to leave as well.

The main different here is the `$` -> **Regular user** and `#` -> **Super User**